# Looking for a (Chrome?) script to automatically log into multiple Gmail accounts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

A while back Google added a multiple sign on system, allowing you to sign into multiple Gmail accounts in a single browser.

If you maintain more than a couple of Gmail accounts then signing in them all is a pain. Are there any Chrome extensions, or other scripts (AHK or whatever) that automate signing into Multiple accounts?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to.  You can just use Google's [multiple sign-in feature](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=28776).

Make sure that you [enable multiple sign in...](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181599), but be warned: Google's offline products like Offline Gmail, Offline Calendar... that is all explained in the link above.

For more help, visit the [Google Accounts Help pages](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/)

Comment: I mean the actual process of clicking login 5 times, entering 5 email addresses and 5 passwords is tedious. I'm looking for something to automate the logging in process.

Comment: @wizlog The original poster already references multiple sign on...

Comment: I would also love to see something like this!